How can I verify the certificates used by an Azure DPS or IoT Hub in the cloud?
To ensure the correct certificate chain is in place for Azure IoT services, it's important to verify the root and intermediate certificates presented by the DPS or IoT Hub. This is especially critical when migrating from Baltimore to DigiCert Global G2. Is there a method to view the certificates being presented by Azure IoT services?

You can use the OpenSSL command on Linux to display the certificate chain for Azure DPS or IoT Hub. Here's the command:
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect [servicename].azure-devices-provisioning.net:443
Replace [servicename] with your DPS or IoT Hub name. This will show the entire certificate chain, including root and intermediate certificates. This is a useful way to confirm that the DPS or IoT Hub is using the correct certificates, such as those from DigiCert Global G2 during the migration process.
For example:
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect your-dps-service.azure-devices-provisioning.net:443
This will return details about the certificates presented by the service, helping to verify if the DigiCert Global G2 root has been implemented.
